# Angular2 QuickStart npm version error

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, dependencies

The Quickstart docs are very clear in saying that **Node version 4.x.x or 5.x.x** and **npm version 3.x.x** are needed and all others will cause errors, but installing the latest *stable* nodejs (on Win-x64) gives me **Node.js v4.6.0** and **npm v2.15.9**

The official Node.js source offers me npm v3.10.3 only if I choose to install Node v6.7.0

Can anyone tell me how I can get **Node 4/5** along with **npm 3** ?

--- Edit
OK. I pulled an earlier release from the node js site and have node 5 with npm 3.

I guess my question is less about node/npm and more about why the Angular team are so clear about **not** using version 6 of node.

Comment: You can upgrade npm using this command - `npm install -g npm`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node.JS 4.6.0 isn't the latest *stable* version but the **Long Term Support** version. 
[6.7.0](https://nodejs.org/dist/v6.7.0/node-v6.7.0-x64.msi) is the current stable release. You can download that confidently in order to support NPM 3.x.x and Angular 2.